# Get Excel comment cell reference directly using Office.js

Tags: excel, office-js

I need to read all the comments in an Excel worksheet with the related cell references, using Office.js.

I don't know in which cells the comments are, I'm able to access to Excel.CommentCollection object and read all the comments information, but I cannot find a way to get the comment cell reference, is there a way to get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getLocation()` to get the Range object, then you can get the cell reference form range

```
getLocation(): Excel.Range;
```

you can find the document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.comment?view=excel-js-preview#getlocation--